# Read space as input in shell script

Tags: shell, quoting, read

How can I give space `" "` as input in shell script ?

Ex :

```
echo " Enter date for grep... Ex: Oct  6 [***Double space is important for single date***] (or) Oct 12 "
read mdate 
echo $mdate
```

I get the output as `Oct 6` but I want `Oct  6`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already have `Oct  6` in `$mdate`, your problem is that you're expanding it when printing. **[Always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)**. Additionally, to retain leading and trailing whitespace (those are stripped by `read`), set `IFS` to the empty string.

```
IFS= read -r mdate
echo "$mdate"
```

The `-r` (**r**aw) option to read tells it not to treat backslashes specially, which is what you want most of the time (but it's not the problem here).

Comment: can we also ensure the beginning and ending spaces are not dropped? `read toto ; echo "$toto"` : when i enter `______this____`  (_ are spaces) it outputs `this` (I believe this is not something done by read, but by the shell's line policy? how to change it? stty raw before the read, or something?)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Yes, this needed `IFS=`. This is about the shell, it has nothing to do with terminal settings.

Comment: I found it : `OLDIFS="$IFS" ; IFS="" read toto ; echo "__${toto}__" ; IFS="${OLDIFS}"`

Comment: oh; thanks for that quick reply, that I only saw when I typed my 2nd comment ^^  +1, sir!

Comment: @OlivierDulac No need for anything so complicated. Just set `IFS` for the duration of the `read` call.

Comment: I need coffee... indeed: `IFS='' read toto` will change IFS just for the duration of the call to read ... (I know this, usually...)